# Continuity of the joint distribution function given continuity of marginals

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables such that $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are the respective distribution functions. Suppose $F_X$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $F_Y$ is continuous at $y_0$. Then show that $F_{X,Y}$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ where $F_{X,Y}$ is the joint distribution function.

I am highly doubtful about the rigor of my method but here is my attempt:

> Consider any sequence $\{x_n,y_n\}$ converging to $(x_0,y_0)$. Then $x_n\to x_0$ and $y_n\to y_0$. Hence $F_X(x_n)\to F_X(x_0)$ and $F_Y(y_n)\to F_Y(y_0)$.
>
> Now fix $m$. Then consider the corresponding subsequence $(x_n,y_m)_n$ of $(x_n,y_n)$. Then $F_{X,Y}(x_n,y_m)=P(X\leq x_n,Y\leq y_m)\to P(X\leq x_0,Y\leq y_m)=F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_m)$ by continuity property of $F_X$, and noting that $m$ is fixed. Now letting $m\to\infty$, we obtain $\lim_{m\to\infty}F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_m)=F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_0)$ and hence $\lim_m\lim_nF_{X,Y}(x_n,y_n)=F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_0)$.
>
> By taking limits the other way, we similarly obtain $\lim_n\lim_mF_{X,Y}(x_n,y_m)=F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_0)$. So both the iterated limits exist and are equal, concluding that $\lim_{m,n}F_{X,Y}(x_n,y_m)=F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_0)$

This is true for every sequence $(x_n,y_n)\to(x_0,y_0)$ so the problem is solved.

EDIT: While conversing with Dilip Sarwate, I realized that the problem does not make sense if $X,Y$ are not jointly continuous. So I throw in this supposition: $X,Y$ are jointly continuous as well.

Comment: Have you tried to see if your argument breaks down anywhere in the case  when $Y$ is a (continuous) _function_ of $X$? For example, $Y=X^2$ so that the random variables are not _jointly_ continuous even though they are _marginally_ continuous?

Comment: So what should a correct proof be? Please share it.

Comment: Perhaps there is no proof? If $X$ and $Y$ are _continuous_ random variables, it is not necessarily true that they are _jointly_ continuous.

Comment: So if I suppose that they are jointly continuous, then could you sketch a proof as the answer? I will accept it if I find it understandable. Thanks!

Comment: So is the method fine, given that $X,Y$ are jointly continuous?

Comment: @DilipSarwate On your first comment: I agree that in the case you mention there is no PDF for the joint distribution (so not absolutely continuous), but the CDF $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is continuous. Also see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2023980/75923).

Answer (score 0):

So I thought it over and decided to post a solution to this problem. Please check if this is correct. This approach differs from what I wrote in the question only in terms of rigor.

> Define the events $A_n=\{X\leq x_n\}$ and $B_m=\{Y\leq y_m\}$, where $n,m\in\mathbb N$. Also define $A=\{X\leq x_0\}$ and $B=\{Y\leq y_0\}$.
>
> Now, it is given that $P(A_n)\to P(A)$ as $n\to\infty$ and $P(B_m)\to P(B)$ as $m\to \infty$.
>
> Fix $m$. Then $P(A_n,B_m)$ is a sequence in $n$. Then,  $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n,B_m)=a_m$ exists. I want to show that $a_m=P(A,B_m)$.

The proof to this, however, is non-rigorous, but I think it works.

> After fixing $m$, we have restricted the movement of $Y$, so basically we are looking at movements of $X$ now. $Y$ does not get out of $B_m$, while $X$ may go on dancing, provided that $x_n\to x_0$. So essentially, $P(A_n,B_m)\to P(A,B_m)$ because $\{A_n,B_m\}\to\{A,B\}$ and $P(A_n)\to P(A)$.

This is a terrible way of writing it but sorry, this is the best I can do!!

Anyway, after this:

> Similarly $\lim_{m\to\infty}P(A,B_m)=P(A,B)$. Also for each $m$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n,B_m)$ exists (due to the horrible argument above).
>
> Thus I show the existence of the final limit $\lim_{m\to\infty,n\to\infty}P(A_n,B_m)=P(A,B)$ using the theorem in Double Sequences which states that if $s_{n,m}$ be a double sequence such that $\lim_m\lim_ns_{n,m}=a$ and $\lim_na_{n,m}$ exists uniformly for $m$ then $\lim_{m,n}s_{n,m}=a$.

I am just not sure if I can apply these in the above ways I have shown.