# Is there a two-dimensional random variable whose CDF is continuous, but whose marginal CDFs are discontinuous?

Tags: probability-theory

Is there a two-dimensional random variable $(X,Y)$, whose CDF is continuous, but whose marginal CDFs are discontinuous?

My question differs from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023893) in that a random variable that has a continuous CDF, which is the condition stipulated in my question, is not necessarily a continuous random variable, which is the condition stipulated in the other question. Thus, my question is more general than the other one.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but if you ask the same for PDFs instead of CDFs, then the answer is Yes. See [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=irKSXZ7kKFgC&lpg=PA34&ots=tZ1xcfyklM&dq=continuous%20joint%20but%20discontinuous%20marginal&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q=continuous%20joint%20but%20discontinuous%20marginal&f=false)

Comment: I have written a thorough answer on the connection between continuity of CDFs and their marginals here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2023980/259493

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is negative even for coordinatewise continuity.

Let $F_X$ be discontinuous in $x_0$. Then $P(X=x_0)>0$, and, thanks to the continuity of probability, $P(X=x_0,Y\le y)>0$ for some $y\in \mathbb{R}$. However, the continuity of $F_{X,Y}$ in $x$ implies
$$
P(X=x_0,Y\le y) = \lim_{x\to x_0-}P(X\in(x_0,x],Y\le y)\\
=\lim_{x\to x_0-}\big(F_{X,Y}(x_0,y)-F_{X,Y}(x,y)\big)  =0,
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: In the last line, I think you that you have the same thing before and after the "=" sign.

Comment: +1! I will delete my comment then, since it is now obsolete!