# Deduce continuity of joint CDF from continuity of marginals

Tags: probability, continuity

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with CDF $F$. In general, continuity of the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ does not allow one to conclude that $F$ is continuous. Under what conditions can we conclude that $F$ is continuous as well --- I think independence of $X$ and $Y$ is a special case under which this holds true, but are there other special cases?

The reason I am asking this is because I came across the following:
we have a sequence of i.i.d random vectors $\{(X_i, Y_i)\}$ and we suppose there exists a normalization such that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(\frac{\max(X_1,...,X_n)-b_n}{a_n}\leq x,\frac{\max(Y_1,...,Y_n)-d_n}{c_n}\leq y)=G(x,y)$$ for all continuity points of the distribution function $G$ with nondegenerate marginals. Then, the author shows that the marginals must be continuous and concludes that $G$ must be continuous as well. Why is this true?

(this is from page 209 of "Extreme Value Theory, De Haan & Ferreira")

Comment: What is your definition of a random vector that is continuous? If it is enough that the CDF is continuous (so no PDF is required) then I think that continuity of the marginals of $G(x,y)$ implies continuity of $G(x,y)$. For a proof of that see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2023980/75923).

Comment: I mean that the CDF is continuous, thank you for the link. So I think my confusion arose from the fact that we do not necessarily have absolute continuity then ( counter example X=Y for instance), but marginal continuity of CDF's does imply continuity of the joint CDF?

Comment: Then you are practicizing the correct definition for continuity of random variable/vector. Quite often there is confusion on this topic. E.g. see the comments on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1239329/75923). Another thing: "Laurens de Haan" is my promotor ;).

Comment: Small world, I think we will meet one day :)